# JSON from MongoDB to CSV, then transpose rows

Tags: json, mongodb, postgresql, csv, relational-database

I have some JSON data that looks like this:

```
[{
        id: "1",
        quantity: "3",
        date: "2016-10-31T02:35:37.587Z"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        quantity: "5",
        date: "2016-10-31T02:35:37.587Z"
    }, {
        id: "1",
        quantity: "4",
        date: "2016-11-01T03:42:22.711Z"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        quantity: "0",
        date: "2016-11-01T03:42:22.711Z"
    }, {
        ...
```

The JSON is coming out of a MongoDB database. I can easily dump it to the following csv:

```
id   |    quantity   |    date
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |        3      |      2016-10-31T02:35:37.587Z 
2    |        5      |      2016-10-31T02:35:37.587Z
1    |        4      |      2016-11-01T03:42:22.711Z 
2    |        0      |      2016-11-01T03:42:22.711Z
```

But what I really want is tabular data that looks like this:

```
id   |    2016-10-31T02:35:37.587Z   |    2016-11-01T03:42:22.711Z
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |                3              |               4 
2    |                5              |               0
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this last table? I'm open to doing operations on MongoDB or on the dumped csv file using PostgreSQL (I've tried using crosstab for this but couldn't get it to work).

Keep in mind that this is a large dataset, with 600k rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with a small js script. It works with the data you provided, but to make it work 'out of the box' you need to make sure that you have the same number of different date for each id. However, if it's not the case, you can easily modify the script.

**script.js:** (generate tab separated cvs, but can be change to whatever you want)

```
// aggregation query, group by id and push other fiels in an array
var cursor = db.collection.aggregate([
          {$group:  
             { _id: "$id",
               date: {$push: "$date"},
               quantity: {$push: "$quantity"}
             }
          }])

// after this cursor content looks like 
// { "_id" : "2", "date" : [ "2016-10-31T02:35:37.587Z", "2016-11-01T03:42:22.711Z" ], "quantity" : [ "5", "0" ] }
// { "_id" : "1", "date" : [ "2016-10-31T02:35:37.587Z", "2016-11-01T03:42:22.711Z" ], "quantity" : [ "3", "4" ] }


var item; 
var headers; 
var content;
var nb = -1;

// iterate over the results
while (cursor && cursor.hasNext()){
   item = cursor.next();
   // print headers
   if (nb<0){
     headers = 'id';
       for (var i =0; i<item.date.length; i++) {
         headers += '\t' + item.date[i];
      }
    print(headers);
    nb++; 
  }
  // print content
  content = item._id;
  for (var j=0; j<item.quantity.length; j++){
    content += '\t' + item.quantity[j];
  }
  print('\n' +content );
}
```

to use it, enter this command :

```
mongo dbName --quiet < script.js
```

this will print

```
id  2016-10-31T02:35:37.587Z    2016-11-01T03:42:22.711Z

2   5   0

1   3   4
```

so you can write to an output file like this (on unix like OS)

```
mongo dbName  --quiet < script.js > output.csv
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I just removed the `'\n'` in the second to last line because it was adding empty rows in the .csv file.